# Determining Quotient group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be the group of linear functions under addition. Let $H$ be the subgroup of $G$ containing only the linear functions passing through the origin.

How do I determine the group $G/H.$ What are the steps I need to follow?

Comment: What's a linear function to you? Is if a function $f(x) = ax + b$? Or is it a function $f(x)$ such that for any scalars $a,b$ and elements $x,y$ of the domaon, $f(ax + by) = af(x) + bf(y)$?

Comment: I believe it's the function $f(x) = ax + b$.

Comment: You need to provide some additional information for this to be answerable. Linear functions from where to where? Also, the functions you mean are usually called affine, rather than linear. My guess would be that these are from the reals to the reals, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

$H=\{kx:k\in{\mathbb{R}}\}$,and therefore elements in G/H has the form of $ax+b+H=b+H$,thus $G/H=\{b+H:b\in{\mathbb{R}}\}$.